# Evaluate Operator Symbol and Perform Operator

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a form that ends up resulting in having a `string Qty`, `string SelectedQtyOperator` from a combobox that has `>`, `==`, `<=` and the like, and database `?int` column `Qty`. I'm trying to find some way to evaluate this inside a LINQ expression without writing an ifelse/switch statement for each option.

Currently I have:

```
data = data.Where(m => Convert.ToInt32(m.Qty) [somehow evaluate SlQtyOp] Convert.ToInt32(Qty)).Select(m => m);
```

Is it possible to do this inside the expression or have some type of helper function that evaluates it and returns the proper expression?

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention `data` is initialized as :

```
var data = db.MyDatabase.Select(m => m);
```

where db is a DataContext

**For Those Using LINQ-to-Object and reading this**

While I was trying to do this in **LINQ-to-SQL** (which I by my own negligence didn't initially mention), **Jim Mischel** & **Sriram Sakthivel** posted different solutions that may aid you.

Comment: When using LINQ in Query Syntax you can use the [let clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383976.aspx) to evaluate and store some value for later use in the query.

Comment: What's the point of using `Select(m => m)` here?

Comment: I thought Select was needed, even if it was for all, just the way I self learned it is all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `if-else` or `switch`, you can't do that with LINQ, you will need [Dyamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

I would do something like this:

```
bool IsLessThan(int a, int b)
{
    return a < b;
}

bool IsGreaterThan(int a, int b)
{
    return a > b;
}
```

Create `IsEqual`, `IsLessEqual`, `IsGreaterEqual` and `IsNotEqual` in the same way.

And create a delegate:

```
Func<int, int, bool> comparisonFunc;
```

And before you call the LINQ, you assign the delegate:

```
switch (oper)
{
    case "<" : comparisonFunc = IsLessThan; break;
    case ">" : comparisonFunc = IsGreaterThan; break;
    // etc.
}
```

Your LINQ expression then becomes:

```
data = data.Where(m => comparisonFunc(m.Qty, Convert.ToInt32(Qty))).Select(m => m);
```

Now, if some of your fields are `int`, some are `double`, etc., then your methods are slightly different:

```
bool IsLessThan(int rslt)
{
    return rslt < 0;
}

bool IsGreaterEqual(int rslt)
{
    return rslt >= 0;
}
```

And so on. Your delegate is slightly different:

```
Func<int, bool> comparisonFunc;
```

And you use the `IComparer` for the type in your LINQ expression:

```
data = data.Where(m => comparisonFunc(m.Qty.CompareTo(Convert.ToInt32(Qty)))).Select(m => m);
```

Or, if it's a `double`:

```
data = data.Where(m => comparisonFunc(m.Qty.CompareTo(Convert.ToDouble(Qty)))).Select(m => m);
```

By the way, in this case there's no need for the `Select`. You're not doing a projection (i.e. you're taking the object as-is), so you can eliminate the `Select`.

Comment: You could also define a `Dictionary<string, Func<int, int, bool>>` to map the values, instead of a `switch`, which I find to be somewhat cleaner, but the concept is the same.

Comment: Testing it out, this works in LINQ-to-Object, but since I'm doing LINQ-to-SQL (sorry for not originally mentioning that), it has no supported translation to SQL. Thanks though.

Comment: @Servy: Good point. I would find the Dictionary cleaner, too. Didn't think of it at the time. *shrug*

Comment: @PRX It's certainly possible to modify this solution to use expressions instead of functions.  When you don't specify things like that up front you can't exactly expect people to know it.

Answer (score 1):

One trivial way of dealing with the task that does not require using additional libraries would be constructing your query in parts: start by querying the table and adding other `Where` clauses that you may have. After that, construct a simple `switch` statement like this:

```
IQueryable<MyDataType> data = ... // Put the initial query/table here
var qty = Convert.ToInt32(Qty);
switch (SelectedQtyOperator) {
    case ">": data = data.Where(m.Qty > qty ); break;
    case "<": data = data.Where(m.Qty < qty ); break;
    case "==": data = data.Where(m.Qty == qty ); break;
    case ">=": data = data.Where(m.Qty >= qty ); break;
    case "<=": data = data.Where(m.Qty <= qty ); break;
    default: /* Throw an exception: this shouldn't happen */ break;
}
foreach (var d in data) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do something with reflection I would think but something like this works as well:

```
switch (SlQtyOp)
{
case ">":
    data = data.Where(m => m.Qty > Convert.ToInt32(Qty)).Select(m => m);
case "<":
    data = data.Where(m => m.Qty < Convert.ToInt32(Qty)).Select(m => m);
case "=":
    data = data.Where(m => m.Qty = Convert.ToInt32(Qty)).Select(m => m);
}
```

It's probably easiest to just use the switch though.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid XD

Answer (score 0):

So, given that this is for an `IQueryable`, and not an `IEnumerable`, you'll need to manipulate expressions, rather than functions.  To start with we'll define a dictionary that has the string version of each operator and maps it to an expression representing that operation:

```
var mappings = new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<int, int, bool>>>()
{
    {">", ( Expression<Func<int, int, bool>>)((a,b)=> a > b)},
    {"<", ( Expression<Func<int, int, bool>>)((a,b)=> a < b)},
    {"==", ( Expression<Func<int, int, bool>>)((a,b)=> a == b)},
};
```

other operations can be added.

There is also a helper method that we'll use to replace all instance of one expression with another throughout some expression.

It uses this visitor:

```
public class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

And is just wraps it in a cleaner syntax:

```
public static Expression Replace(this Expression expression,
    Expression searchEx, Expression replaceEx)
{
    return new ReplaceVisitor(searchEx, replaceEx).Visit(expression);
}
```

From there we move on to the meat of the problem, creating an operation that filters a given query where the two given operands are evaluated using a given operator.  It'll take the query to be filtered, selectors for each operand, and then the operation.  It then replaces all instances of the parameters of the operation with the operand selectors, and replaces the right selector's parameter with that of the left's, so that there is one actual parameter in the final product, which is then wrapped up into a lambda and passed to `Where`:

```
public static IQueryable<TIn> WhereOperator<TIn, TLeft, TRight>(
    this IQueryable<TIn> query,
    Expression<Func<TIn, TLeft>> leftSelector,
    Expression<Func<TIn, TRight>> rightSelector,
    Expression<Func<TLeft, TRight, bool>> operation)
{
    var newRightBody = rightSelector.Body.Replace(rightSelector.Parameters[0],
        leftSelector.Parameters[0]);
    var newOperator = operation.Body.Replace(operation.Parameters[0], leftSelector.Body)
        .Replace(operation.Parameters[1], newRightBody);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TIn, bool>>(newOperator,
        leftSelector.Parameters[0]);
    return query.Where(lambda);
}
```

Example usage:

```
IQueryable<Tuple<int, int>> query = new[] { Tuple.Create(1, 2) }
    .AsQueryable();

var query2 = query.WhereOperator(pair => pair.Item1, pair => pair.Item2
    , mappings[">"]);
```

In this case we're using in memory queryables, but as `query2.Expression` will show you, this actually looks identical to having called:

```
var query3 = query.Where(pair => pair.Item1 > pair.Item2);
```